# Understanding Time Slice and Execution Time

Tags: java

i was given an assignment .

> Write a program to simulate job scheduling in an operating system.
>   Jobs are generated at random  times. Each job is given both a random
>   priority from 1 to 4 – where 1 is the highest priority –and  a random
>   amount of time to complete its execution.
>
> Jobs do not begin execution and run to completion, but instead share
>   the processor. The  operating system executes a job for a fixed unit
>   of time called time slice. At the end of the time  slice, the current
>   job’s execution is suspended. The job is then placed on a priority
>   queue, where  it waits for its next share of processor time. The job
>   having the highest priority is then removed  from the priority queue
>   and executed for a time slice. When a job is first generated, it will
>   begin executing immediately if the processor is free.  Otherwise it
>   will be placed on the priority queue.
>
> In this assignment, you will need an implementation of a queue and a
>   priority queue. You can  use the priority queue in the Java Class
>   Library (java.util.PriorityQueue). It implements the  interface
>   java.util.Queue.

im confuse with time slice and execution time..
as my understanding for now is let say final int timeslice=3, the time to complete all job is final int clock=20 minutes.;
when  job A begin at 0 minute has execution time of 5(which is randomly generated between 1-5).
while executing the job till minute 3.Job A is put into priority queue while Job B with execution time of 2 minute enters at minute 3? after finish executing Job B, Job A enter to finish executing or Job C ?

please explain if im wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question of whether Job A or Job C is executed (once B is complete) it should depend what the PriorityQueue returns, which will be the job with the highest priority.

If Job A had a priority of 1 and Job C a priority of 2, PriorityQueue would return Job A and that should get the next time slice.

If Job C had a priority of 2 and Job B a priority of 4, PriorityQueue would return Job C and that should get the next time slice.

As adn_295 says, this is a good assignment.

Answer (score 0):

PriorityQueue always returns the highest priority task, so it will keep being returned whenever add back to the queue.  I suggest you try implementing the solution as see how it works. (Or writing a simple test program using PriorityQueue)

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is a very good assignment.! You need to implement the exact mechanism of how OS works to schedule jobs/tasks. See these references to get clear understanding of it.

1) http://oreilly.com/java/archive/quartz.html

2)[Job Scheduling Problem in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4423712/1130032)